# c++ template call of function pointer type

Tags: c++, templates

If I have type declarations like

```
typedef void (*command)();

template <command c>
void execute() {
   c();
}

void task() { /* some piece of code */ }
```

then

```
execute<task>();
```

will compile and behaves as expected. However if I define the template as

```
template <command c>
void execute() {
   command();
}
```

it still compiles. I did this by accident. Now I am confused of what the second version would be expected to do.

Comment: `command();` creates a temporary object of the function *pointer* type defined by the `typedef`.

Comment: Is something wrong in calling `execute(command)`;? Why you want to use such an hybrid pattern?

Comment: This is a stripped down example. What I actually did is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19611077/2036917 The point is that the template allows me to have different instances of static variables. I know that I could achieve the same with suitable objects. But then again remember that an Arduino has only 2K of RAM. So thus approach reduces the memory footprint a little bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++

```
type_name()
```

is an expression that creates a default-initialized instance of `type_name`.

For natives types there are implicitly defined default constructors, so for example

```
int();
```

is a valid C++ statement (just creates an `int` and throws it away).

`g++` with full warnings on emits a diagnostic message because it's a suspect (possibly unintended) operation, but the code is valid and there can even be programs depending on it (if the type is a user-defined type and the constructor of the instance has side effects).

Comment: That sounds right: writting `command temp=command();` also compiles and assigns to `temp` the value 0

Comment: @memo1288: Yes... and for native types it's different from `command temp;` (that doesn't sound too right)

Answer (score 4):

```
command();
```

It creates a temporary object like `TYPE();` and compiler omits it as an *unused* variable.

```
warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     command();
     ^
```

You should turn on `-Wall` compiler's option. [*Live code.*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe3fe69a9c1c6647)